# Autohotkey send shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, shortcut

I want to add some keypresses after a shortcut in Visual Studio.
When pressing the shortcut `Ctrl + 0, Ctrl + G` it should be executed in Visual Studio and after that 9 Tabs should be pressed.

I came up with this:

```
^0::
IfWinActive Visual Studio
{
    Input, OutputVar, T1 L1
    if OutputVar == g
        Send, ^0^g
        Send, {Tab}
        Send, {Tab}
        Send, {Tab}
        Send, {Tab}
        Send, {Tab}
        Send, {Tab}
        Send, {Tab}
        Send, {Tab}
        Send, {Tab}
}
return
```

The check for the shortcut works so far, but sending `^0^g` it does nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, note the changes made and the links to the documentation for further details.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

#IfWinActive Visual Studio ; a lot easier to use for context sensitive hotkeys
$^0:: ; for more info on $ see http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols
; Store the character for Ctrl-G in the CtrlG var. (7th letter)
; See doc http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Input.htm
Transform, CtrlG, Chr, 7
Input, OutputVar, T1 M L1 ; forgot the M option here
If OutputVar = %CtrlG%
    { ; don't forget the {} block after an if condition http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Block.htm
     Send, ^0^g
     Send, {Tab 9}
    }
Return
```

Comment: doesn't work :( shouldn't the comparison be %OutputVar% ? OutputVar is empty when when I hold Ctrl while pressing G

Comment: Sorry, forgot the M option in the Input command - should work now. You can compare  `If OutputVar = %CtrlG%` OR  `If (OutputVar = CtrlG)`